# Xamarin error code 34018

Tags: ios, xamarin

I've been dealing with this issue when I run my app via debug on simulator, as soon as I upgraded to the latest Xcode 8.0 and OS version 10.11.6. Error below:

Application Settings exception, Unable to store key CognitoIdentity:IdentityId:eu-west-1:*KEY*, got error: -34018.

Seems it's linked to the keychain but haven't got a solution on Xamarin yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should check out this bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43514

It is probably the same :)

Comment: This is why you should copy answers from outside sites and not just link. I can't access that link.

Comment: @Medo it was accessible at the time of the response. Please see suggestion below

Comment: I can't access the link either

Answer (score 15):

Here's what I did based on DDerTyp's suggestion

1. Add an "Entitlements.plist" file to the project.
2. Click the checkbox "Enable Keychain Access Groups" to enable it.
3. Save the "Entitlements.plist" file.
4. Add the "Entitlements.plist" file under "Project Options > Build > iOS Bundle Signing > Custom Entitlements".

Answer (score 3):

From Brendan Zagaeski's comment in https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44361#c3

> In further study of the workaround, I found that it was not in fact
>   necessary to enable "Keychain Access Groups" in the Entitlements.plist
>   file.  It was sufficient just to add *any* Entitlements.plist file
>   (even one with no property keys).
>
> ### Workaround in Xamarin Studio on Mac
>
> 1. Add an "iOS > Property List" to the project and name it "Entitlements.plist".
> 2. Add the "Entitlements.plist" file under "Project Options > Build > iOS Bundle Signing > Custom Entitlements".
>
> (Be sure to follow step 5 for the "iPhoneSimulator" configuration, and
>   not just the "iPhone" configuration.)
>
> 3. Save the project properties and re-deploy the app to the simulator.
>
> ### Workaround in Visual Studio
>
> 1. Add a new "Apple > Misc > Entitlements.plist" file to the top level of the project.
> 2. Add the "Entitlements.plist" file under "Project properties > iOS Bundle Signing > Custom Entitlements".
>
> (Be sure to follow step 2 for the "iPhoneSimulator" configuration, and
>   not just the "iPhone" configuration.)
>
> 3. Save the project properties and re-deploy the app to the simulator.

(The original text from the link mentioned a Xamarin VS file selector bug that has since been fixed)

Comment: I added the existing (default) Entitlements.plist file as a Custom Entitlement, and this worked too. So there's no need to specially create a new Entitlements.plist file.